# IIS 10 web routing configuration

Tags: asp.net, web, iis, url-routing

I am not sure how this done or what I need to do, I think all I need is a simple rewrite rule but I do not know.

I have a website that [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) loads the site, but when I browse to mysite.com it goes to a different page that basically says pageOk. I am not sure where that redirect is happening - as this was occurring with our old server (some one else managed that) - I installed IIS on a new server and so now the traffic at [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) is fine but I still have this issue of mysite.com showing a page that I do not have in my application.

What do I need to do to fix this or where might this issue be coming from ?

Comment: Combine the logs from browser side tool Fiddler and IIS side failed request tracing, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis you should be able to track down all HTTP requests and responses. Then I believe you can find the cause.

Answer (score 1):

firest check the do any is URL rewrite rule and HTTP redirect is affecting this. check both server level and site level.

try to run failed request tracing in iis.

check browsers developer tool -> network tab which status code it is showing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis